# How can one complete a set to a vector basis?

Tags: vector-spaces

What are the possible ways of solving next trivial task:
$$
\mathbf{u} =
\left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
2 \\
0 \\
\end{array} \right)
\mathbf{v} =
\left( \begin{array}{c}
5 \\
5 \\
2 \\
\end{array} \right) \\ $$

Complete the set $\{u,v\}$ to a vector basis of the vector space $\mathbb{R^3}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so there is a way which allows to do that without thinking. If $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent, then the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) 
$$
w:=u\times v
$$
automatically gives you a basis $(u,v,w)$.

Of course, with some little experience, you see at once that $w=(1,0,0)$ works also without any computation. For instance, the matrix with columns $(w,u,v)$ is then upper triangular. So the determinant is the product of the diagonal coefficients: $1\cdot 2\cdot 5=10\neq 0$. This proves that $(w,u,v)$ is a basis.

Comment: And where does this rule/principle comes from? I mean, we end up with an orthogonal vector w. But how do we immediately know that it's also linearly independent? Furthermore, does it imply that by using say Gram–Schmidt orthogonality one could obtain k vectors in a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R^n}$ ?

Comment: @DenysS. That's a well-known fact of the cross-product. Orthogonality is a very useful shortcut to prove linear independence. Assume $\lambda u+\mu v+\nu w=0$. Take the inner product $w$: it remains $\nu \|w\|^2=0$ so $\nu =0$. Now use linear independence of $u,v$.

Comment: @DenysS. Gram-Schmidt transforms $k$ linearly independent vectors int an orthonormal set of $k$ vectors. They were already linearly independent at the beginning...

Comment: @julien, thanks, I know the questions are dumb but we've all been there. However, what would one do to compute these for $\mathbb{R^n}$ field?

Comment: @DenysS. You're welcome. You did not ask any dumb question.

Comment: @julien, see edited comment plz. :-)

Comment: @DenysS. I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you mean: given two linearly independent vectors, how to complete them into a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @julien, that's exactly what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Pick any vector for the third vector.

Congratulations; if you haven't done something silly (like pick $\vec{0}$ or $\vec{u}$), you almost certainly have a basis!

Step 2: Check that you have a basis.

If you have bad luck and this check fails, go back to step 1.

Comment: There is no proof that your algorithm stops. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\{u,v,w\}$ will be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ if and only if

$$\det\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c} & & \\ u & v & w\\ & & \end{array}\right)\ne 0$$

this gives you an inequation for $w$.

Comment: This gives an inequality for $\mathbf w$.  It works, but is more work than the other approaches.  Linear dependence is hard, not easy, so missing it is easy.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, but it puts things more formulaically--which may be helpful. But yes, it is, of course the same.

Comment: See Julien's answer for a related response.

Answer (score 0):

Take the standard basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$. Try $\{u,v,e_k\}$. At least one of them will work.

(What I mean is pick $k$, and check if $e_k \in \operatorname{sp} \{u,v\}$. If not, you are finished, if so, pick another $k$ and repeat. Since $\dim \operatorname{sp} \{u,v\} = 2$, and $\dim \operatorname{sp} \{e_k\} = 3$, at least one of them will work.)

Answer (score 0):

You need any three vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ that are not linearly dependent.  If you know about upper triangular matrices, I would just pick $\mathbf{w}=\begin {pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end {pmatrix}$.  Now you just need to show the set is linearly independent.  If we have $a\mathbf u + b\mathbf v+c\mathbf w=0$, first you need $c=0,$ then $b=0$, then $a=0.$